# No CSS showing; OceanWP child-theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

Here is my functions.php file:

```
<?php

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'oceanwp-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme('')->get('Version')
 );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

?>
```

And here is my CSS file:

```
/* 

 Theme Name:   OceanWP Child Theme

 Theme URI:    t3pranchags.com

 Description:  OceanWP Child Theme

 Author:       Christoper Little

 Author URI:   

 Template:     oceanwp

 Version:      1.0

 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later

 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html


 /* == Add your own styles below this line ==
--------------------------------------------*/
```

I am working on a local test site and it is showing up with what looks like no CSS. My child theme is active in WP, but it seems to be breaking the parent theme CSS since no CSS at all is showing. I copied the functions.php file from another site I manage and replaced with the oceanwp for my current site. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You should include both "wp_enqueue_style" function calls inside a function called "my_theme_enqueue_styles" (your custom wp_enqueue_scripts action):

```
<?php

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'oceanwp-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' , '/style-rtl.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme('')->get('Version')
     );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Also make sure you set the handle to "parent-style", as per the documentation:

> If your child theme style.css contains actual CSS code (as it normally
>   does), you will need to enqueue it as well. Setting ‘parent-style’ as
>   a dependency will ensure that the child theme stylesheet loads after
>   it. Including the child theme version number ensures that you can bust
>   cache also for the child theme.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: I copy and and pasted that code in and it still isn't loading the CSS.

Comment: Added a note about the theme handle to be used so the answer is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I ended up changing out $parent_style = 'oceanwp-style'; for $parent_style = 'parent-style'; and it works no. No idea why though!